# Trying to set URL and HTTP.body parameters when using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to set the URL parameters here when doing a post to a REST API and for some reason, they are not appearing on the URL when the request is made.

I have seen the other questions posted, but they only set body parameters, I need to supply application key and session id on URL

```
    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    var urlParams:[String: String] = Dictionary()
    urlParams.updateValue(ACS_API_KEY, forKey: "key")
    urlParams.updateValue(SESSION_ID, forKey: "_session_id")

    // cannot figure out how to set params on URL
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: urlParams).0, uploadData)
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess here is that you are not using a `GET`, `HEAD` or `DELETE` HTTP method in `mutableURLRequest`. If it is any of the others, then Alamofire will automatically encode the parameters into the HTTP body of the request. For more information, refer to the `encode` method under the `URL` case.

As a workaround, you could set the `mutableURLRequest` to a `GET`, run the `encode` method, then apply the URL to a new request. I realize this is a bit of an odd workaround, but it is necessary since your usage case is not the common one that the `ParameterEncoding` enumeration was designed for.

Hopefully that helps shed some light.

Comment: Hi @aaron, if this answer is sufficient could you upvote and mark as such?